# Remove collection from model RacerJS?

Tags: node.js, racerjs

This is my client Side code:

```
model.remove('agent',{'text':'online'});
```

I cant able to remove collection from model,Its shows following error in console

```
Error: remove must be performed under a collection and document id. Invalid path: agent
```

Comment: Maybe RacerJS doesn't allows removing whole collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, it looks like 'path' should be the collectionname.id. In this case, maybe I suppose it should be 'agent.id'.

This blog refers that the path should be in the format collection.documentId.document.

http://blog.derbyjs.com/2012/04/13/derby-v0-dot-3-0/